# Show php page in javascript pop-up window

Tags: javascript, php, popup

I try to show a php page in javascript pop-up, is there posobility to open a page in pop-up ?

I have solutions to open a new page,but I would like to show page content in pop-up window...

```
<script>
function popupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) {
    var left = (screen.width / 2)  - (w / 2);
    var top  = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
    var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="popupCenter('test.php')">show</a>
```

Also, try something with litebox,but no success...

Tnx,
P

Comment: And whats the error? BTW you don't use variables w & h

Comment: HI, error is that I try to open pop-up window, and in this case I open new page, like new browser tab...

Comment: Your code works fine for me. It opens a new popup

Comment: Now work for me too.. Tnx in any case!

Answer (score -1):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}

// -->
</script>
```

Put your page in here

```
<a href="popup.php" onclick="return popitup('popup.php')"
    >Link to popup</a>
```

Don't forget to give 2 places your page name. in href and inside a function.